# xsl:variable assignment clarification

Tags: xslt, xsl-variable

My understanding is that `<xsl:variable>` is immutable and cannot be reassigned.

I am new to XSL and came across a situation like what is in the example below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet>

  <xsl:variable name="temp" select="true()"/>

  <xsl:template name="example">
     <xsl:variable name="temp" select="false()"/>
     <p><xsl:value-of select="$temp"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

</styleheet>
```

I have not found anything definitive as to why this occurs. The only way I can reason that I'm not getting an error and why `temp` will output `false` is that there is a global `temp` variable AND an a local `temp` variable (and somehow are not colliding).

Why am I able to *"reassign"* `temp`?

Comment: The second one is local to the template. You're not overriding it in the true sense, but you are in effect making the outer version inaccessible. [Fiddle](www.xmlplayground.xyz/9Usr9c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to "reassign" (more precisely, to shadow) the variable, because the first binding is at the top-level of the stylesheet, while the second one is in a template.

From [XSLT 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#variables):

> A binding **shadows** another binding if the binding occurs at a point where the other binding is visible, and the bindings have the same name. It is an error if a binding established by an `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` element within a template shadows another binding established by an `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` element also within the template. It is not an error if a binding established by an `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` element in a template shadows another binding established by an `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` top-level element.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that  is immutable and cannot be reassigned.

That assumption is correct. XSLT is a [functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and immutable variables are common in this type of language.

> Why am I able to "reassign" temp?

The reason that happens is defined by the term [Scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). This means that your second definition of the variable `temp` overrides/overlays your first one - unless you leave its scope which is - here - the template. But here (as mentioned by @michael.hor257k in the comments) the scope can only be stylesheet-wide or template-wide - so a redefinition of the variable in the same `xsl:template` - even in another code block - is prohibited.

> The only way I can reason that I'm not getting an error and why temp will output false is that there is a global temp variable AND an a local temp variable

In fact, both variables are local, but on another level. The first definition is at the `xsl:stylesheet` level and the second one at the `xsl:template` level. The first one may be considered a `global` variable, but that's only a matter of definition.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. It is not only a matter of scope. You're not allowed to override a variable defined in the same template, even for a limited scope.